# Mensagem de sucesso após o preenchimento do form PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando criar um formulario simples para registro de visita em um local. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo colocar uma mensagem de "Dados enviado com Sucesso" na mesma página deste formulário. A validação deste formulário, antes do envio ao Banco de Dados, eu fiz em PHP, conforme o código abaixo:

form_contato.php

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>contato</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="mail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu EMail" required>
                    </div>
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" required>
          </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <center><button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success" >Enviar</button></center>
                    </div>
          </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

salva_mensagem.php

```
<?php
    include_once('conexao.php');
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $result_msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensagens_contatos(nome, email, assunto, mensagem, created) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$assunto', '$mensagem', NOW())";
    $resultado_msg_contato= mysqli_query($conn, $result_msg_contato)

?>
```

Comment: Não use Trecho de código (Stack Snippets) para PHP, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Answer (score 2):

Você pode exibir um alert de sucesso, acho que pode fazer assim

```
if($resultado_msg_contato->rowcount()<=0){
    echo '<script>alert("Ocorreu um erro!!"); </script>';
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("Dados enviados com sucesso!!"); </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Antes de tudo faça uma checagem do do `mysqli_query`, para isso use o `mysqli_error($conn)`:

```
if ($resultado_msg_contato) {
    //Mensagem de successo
} else {
    //Mensagem de erro com mysqli_error($conn)
}
```

Você então pode enviar o POST pro mesmo endereço e fazendo o uso de `if` e `isset`, deixe o `action=""` vazio assim:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
```

O código todo deve ficar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>contato</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['assunto'], $_POST['mensagem'])) {
        include_once('conexao.php');

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

        $result_msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensagens_contatos(nome, email, assunto, mensagem, created) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$assunto', '$mensagem', NOW())";
        $resultado_msg_contato= mysqli_query($conn, $result_msg_contato);

        if ($resultado_msg_contato) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Dados enviado com Sucesso!</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Erro:', mysqli_error($conn),'</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="mail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu EMail" required>
                    </div>
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" required>
          </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <center><button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success" >Enviar</button></center>
                    </div>
          </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Ou usando Ajax

Pode usar Ajax (`XmlHttpRequest`) combinado com `addEventListener("submit", ...)` para o envio do form e tratar a resposta no callback:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Defina como true
oReq.open("POST", form.getAttribute("action"), true);

//Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    //Se 4 é que concluiu
    if (oReq.readyState === 4) {

        //Checa o status HTTP
        if (oReq.status >= 200 && oReq.status < 300) {
            if (oReq.responseText === "sucesso") {
                alert("Dados enviados com sucesso");
            } else {
                alert("Erro:" + oReq.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Erro HTTP:" + oReq.status);
        }
    }
};

oReq.send(new FormData(form)); //Envia os campos com a API
```

O `salva_mensagem.php` deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['assunto'], $_POST['mensagem'])) {
    include_once('conexao.php');

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $result_msg_contato = "INSERT INTO mensagens_contatos(nome, email, assunto, mensagem, created) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$assunto', '$mensagem', NOW())";
    $resultado_msg_contato= mysqli_query($conn, $result_msg_contato);

    if ($resultado_msg_contato) {
        echo 'sucesso';
    } else {
        echo 'Erro:', mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>contato</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <form id="meuform" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
                    </div>
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="mail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu EMail" required>
                    </div>
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" required>
          </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <center><button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success" >Enviar</button></center>
                    </div>
          </div>
    </form>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function EnviarForm(e) {
            //Previne enviar o Form normal
            e.preventDefault();

            //Pega o form
            var form = e.target;

            //Previne enviar múltiplas vezes até que o Ajax complete
            if (form.enviando) {
                return;
            }

            form.enviando = true;

            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //form.getAttribute("action") é para pegar o action do Form
            oReq.open("POST", form.getAttribute("action"), true);

            //Função assíncrona que aguarda a resposta
            oReq.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (oReq.readyState === 4) {

                    //desbloqueia o form
                    form.enviando = false;

                    if (oReq.status >= 200 && oReq.status < 300) {
                        if (oReq.responseText === "sucesso") {
                            alert("Dados enviados com sucesso");
                        } else {
                            alert("Erro:" + oReq.responseText);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Erro HTTP:" + oReq.status);
                    }
                }
            };

            oReq.send(new FormData(form)); //Envia os campos com a API FormData
        }

        document.getElementById("meuform").addEventListener("submit", EnviarForm);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma,dentro do seu PHP, basta colocar.

**echo 'Dados enviados com sucesso';**

Lembrando que qualquer outra coisa que você for printar dentro do seu php na tela de display, basta dar o echo na string ou variavel.

Segue um exemplo dos amigos gringos.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877551/how-do-i-return-a-message-after-submitting-a-form-on-my-page-with-php

Answer (score 0):

**A pergunta**  colocar uma mensagem de "Dados enviado com Sucesso" **na mesma página deste formulário**.

basta colocar `onSubmit="alert('Dados enviado com Sucesso.');" >`

no form

`<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php" onSubmit="alert('Dados enviado com Sucesso');">`

exemplo

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest" onSubmit="alert('Dados enviado com Sucesso');">
        <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo" required>
     </div>
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="mail" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu EMail" required>
     </div>
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" name="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" required>
    </div>
     </div>
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <center><button type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success" >Enviar</button></center>
     </div>
    </div>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode definir um balão de notificação com essa mensagem!

No fim do código php, dê refresh na página e mande no url `&f=1`

No balão de texto, adicione `if(isset($_GET['f']))` e meta a mensagem pretendida!

### Por passos

1. Criar balão, recomendo usar [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp) com `position: fixed; right: 10px; bottom:10px;` nos estilos.
2. Usar `<meta refresh>` ou `header('Location: link_do_site');` e adicionar `&f=1`
3. E por último, antes de onde ficará a `div` do `alert`, adicionar `if(isset($_GET['f'])){`.

Deste jeito irá ficar agradável à visão e bastante prático!

Answer (score 0):

Se você colocar esse `script` na sua página, vai aparecer um alert avisando que foi salvo e depois volta pra página anterior. :)

**salva_mensagem.php**

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'seu_banco') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensagens VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$assunto', '$mensagem')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```